# Очистка памяти при закрытии диалоговых окон в Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, gui, jdialog

Допустим, есть у меня главная форма и зависимый JDialog:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame(){
     public MainFrame(){
         /* код создания формы */
         initComponents();
         new JDialog(this, "JD", true).setVisible(true); 
     }
}
```

Если я вызову таким образом диалоговое окно (вообще, любое новое окно), в этом окне нажму на крестик, то очистится ли JDialog из памяти автоматически, так как на него нет ссылок?

Допустим, я вешаю вызов диалогового окна на кнопку. При каждом нажатии будет создаваться новый экземпляр JDialog, но будут ли при этом удалены старые?

Answer (score 3):

> Если я вызову таким образом диалоговое окно( вообще, любое новое окно), в этом окне нажму на крестик, то JDialog автоматически очистится из памяти, так как ссылок нет на него?

По умолчанию очистки памяти не произойдет, для того чтобы при закрытии диалога освободилась память, нужно передать [DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE) в метод [setDefaultCloseOperation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int))

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(this, "JD", true);
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Если один и тот же диалог отображается многократно, то есть более оптимальный подход:

- сохранить диалог в переменной класса;
- отображать его с помощью `setVisible(true)`.

В этом случае создается только один диалог и не нужно думать об утечке памяти при создании новых. Также в этом случае не нужно менять поведение по умолчанию при закрытии.

Из документации [setDefaultCloseOperation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)):

> Sets the operation that will happen by default when the user initiates a "close" on this dialog. You must specify one of the following choices:
>   — DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Don't do anything; require the program to handle the operation in the windowClosing method of a registered WindowListener object.
>   — HIDE_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide the dialog after invoking any registered WindowListener objects.
>   — DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): **Automatically hide and dispose the dialog after invoking any registered WindowListener objects.**
>   **The value is set to HIDE_ON_CLOSE by default.** Changes to the value of this property cause the firing of a property change event, with property name "defaultCloseOperation".

*Вольный перевод*

> Устанавливает операцию, которая будет выполнена при закрытии окна пользователем. Вам нужно указать один из следующих вариантов:
>   — DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE (определен в WindowConstants): ничего не делать; программа должна сама обработать событие закрытия окна;
>   — HIDE_ON_CLOSE (определен в WindowConstants): выполнить все обработчики закрытия окна, после чего скрыть диалог;
>   — DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE (определен в WindowConstants): **выполнить все обработчики закрытия окна, после чего автоматически скрыть диалог и очистить ресурсы.**
>   **По умолчанию установлено значение HIDE_ON_CLOSE.** Изменения значения свойства вызывают событие изменения свойств с ключем "defaultCloseOperation".